# Create wifi network that links to specific server page on boot

Tags: wireless, headless

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 headless with a wifi card. Everything works fine, but I need the box create a wifi point on boot that redirects all connected users to a certain page on the server. Let me know if you have any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

1. Set up Apache on your machine with the web-page you want to show
2. use NAT to redirect all pass-through traffic on port 80 to Apache.

You can find a lot of info on the subject if you google for "iptables". Here's one tutorial (it's about setting up a "transparent proxy", but the idea is absolutely the same):

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

This isn't actually anything to do with wifi - that just provides a network medium.

What you need is to run a web server with a default page to deliver to the users who connect.

As long as the wireless router only allows port 80 (or 443) traffic, and only to that server (very straightforward for any router), users will not actually be able to do anything else.